# regex replace in linux for multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 200k files in a single folder in linux server where i need to transform this files using regex
here is the regex to find in text file

```
([^\s]+?.*)=((.*(?=,$))+|.*).*
```

now I need to replace it with below substitution value

```
"$1":"$2",
```

the above regex is working fine when i used them in python. the server which i am working does not
support python, so i need to use bash commands. i have tried below bash command but it is not working

command:

```
sed -r  's/([^\s]+?.*)=((.*(?=,$))+|.*).*/"$1":"$2",/g' *20200502*
```

the above bash command is not working

Comment: `sed` does not understand `[\s]` and such but `[[:space:]]` which are POSIX's named character classes. See: [wikibooks.org: POSIX Extended Regular Expressions § Character classes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions#Character_classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your regex:

```sh
sed -E 's/([^[:space:]]+?.*)=((.*(=?,$))+|.*).*/"\1":"\2",/g' *20200502*
```

1. Replaced inappropriate `[^\s]` by its POSIX ERE syntax equivalent `[^[:space:]]`.
2. Fixed the misplaced optional marker `?=,$` with `=?,$` instead.
3. Fixed the invalid capture group reference syntax `"$1":"$2"` with `"\1":"\2"`.

Answer (score -1):

Kinda difficult to test but just analyzing your approach this might work:

```
sed -i -E "s/([^\s]+?.*)=((.*(?=,$))+|.*).*/\1$1\2$2/" *20200502*
```

- \1 and \2 in the second part are references to the groups captured in the first part
- -E for extended regular expressions (+ and grouping)

Comment: hi @nikoksr i am getting same error as before error:- sed: -e expression #1, char 38: Invalid preceding regular expression